# Comparing two strings in Java using charAt

Tags: java, string, charat

I must compare two strings using charAt() function and return true if the strings are the same or false if they arent

```
public static boolean comparaStringhe(String word1, String word2) {
    if (word1.length() == word2.length()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < word1.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < word2.length(); j++) {
                if (word1.charAt(i) == word2.charAt(j)) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comparing the following words:
1. test - test /
2. test - Test /
3. test - tEst /
4. tEsT- tesT

Actual output:
1. true
2. false
3. true
4. true

Expected output:
1. true
2. false
3. false
4. false

Comment: You should not return `true` when the first characters match, you have to continue looking at the rest. Also, no need to compare characters for `i != j` (no need to even have two loops really).

Comment: You only compare the first character and then return true. Please debug/step through your code to see where you went wrong

Comment: What should i return after word1.charAt(i) == word2.charAt(i) ?? I understand why my program isn't working, but I cant understand how to fix it

Comment: Why you have 2 `for`s? You take first `char` from `word1` and compare with all from `word2` and than second `char` from `word1` with all from `word2`...

Comment: You don't return anything when 2 chars are equal. Basically you could do the following: 1) compare the lengths and if they are different return false 2) loop over the characters and compare them. When you find 2 different chars at the _same_ index you return false 3) if you reach the end the strings are equal so you return true.

Answer (score 6):

Two problems with your code:
1. no need for double loop, you are comparing each char on the first word to each char on the second, that's wrong. one loop is enough, and compare `word1.charAt(i) == word2.charAt(i)`
2. you are returning true if the first char is equal, and not continuing to the rest of the words. the `return true` should come only after the for loop as ended

```
public static boolean comparaStringhe(String word1, String word2) {
        if (word1.length() == word2.length()) {
            for(int i=0; i<word1.length(); i++) {
                    if(word1.charAt(i) != word2.charAt(i)) {
                        return false;
                    }
            }
            return true;
        }

        return false;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for two loops when both Strings have the same length. Also just return `false` in case of a mismatch. When the loop will finish it will mean that there were no mismatches and `true` can be returned.

Answer (score -1):

You are returning before the code has a chance to go through the whole string.

return only after the whole string has been traversed.

```
for(int i=0; i<word1.length(); i++) 
{
    for(int j=0; j<word2.length(); j++) 
    {
        if(word1.charAt(i) == word2.charAt(j)) 
        {
            // return true; the code is not able to traverse through the whole string.
        } 
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true; // The code has now traversed the whole string and can now say that the strings match. Thus return true.
}
```

Comment: Why do you have two loops?